# trimmingCharacters not work on iOS 10.3 Xcode8.3

Tags: ios, swift, string, xcode8, ios10.3

Please help me, I use Xcode 8.3(swift 3.1), the function `trimmingCharacters` not work. My code as below:

```
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
if var searchStr = textField.text{
       let _searchStr = searchStr.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
       print("After trimming:\(_searchStr)")
   }
}
```

The input in textfield is `409 huỳnh` and the print result is `409 huỳnh` **not as expected: 409huỳnh** .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the documentation:

> A new string made by **removing from both ends** of the receiver characters contained in set.

It does **not** remove characters within the string.

You can replace whitespaces – corresponding to the `.whitespaces` character set –  in the string with regular expression:

```
let _searchStr = searchStr.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\s", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use Swift 5 Character property [`isWhitespace`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/character/3127019-iswhitespace) and filter all non whitespaces from your string:

```
let string = "409 huỳnh"
let result = string.filter { !$0.isWhitespace }
print(result)  // "409huỳnh"
```

Answer (score 2):

`trimmingCharacters` removes only leading and trailing white spaces.

try this

```
let _searchStr = searchStr.replacingOccurrences(" ", withString: "", options:.literal, range: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
let trimmedString = searchStr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

Hope this helps you !

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 3** you can use below code to solve the problem

```
let _searchStr = searchStr.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "")
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4** alternative

Since Swift 4 Strings are Sequences again. You can use a filter to do that.

```
let _searchStr = searchStr.filter({ " ".contains($0) == false })
```